# Existe um canal no irc para o meta e/ou para o próprio Stack Overflow em Português?

Tags: suporte, meta

Procurei no irc e não achei. Também não achei nenhuma informação aqui no site sobre isto. Se ainda não existe, que tal criar?

Comment: Existe um criado por alguns utilizadores [#SOPtMesaDeBar](https://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=SOPtMesaDeBar)

Comment: Já há o chat oficial da rede, que salva o histórico, e tem recursos otimizados para o perfil do site. E com direito à deleção de mensagens baseado na interpretação pessoal do nosso Community Manager do que é ou não dentro das regras :P Segue o link: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910

Comment: Algum de vocês poderia criar uma resposta citando o conteúdo destes dois comentários acima? A junção das informações dos dois me deixou satisfeito. Obrigado!